# iOS how to structure helper class

Tags: ios

I have two classes: one primary one and one helper class. The helper class subclasses a UITableViewController and has no purpose outside of implementing functionality for the primary class. I am unsure how to structure this. Coming from a java background, the natural approach I think of is an inner class but reading other posts that doesn't exist in iOS. What is the proper way to structure this? Just declare the helper class as its own standalone class in separate .h/.m files with the implicit understanding that its a helper class?

Comment: "Just declare the helper class as its own standalone class in separate .h/.m files with the implicit understanding that its a helper class?" Yes

Comment: Why is the helper a subclass of `UITableViewController`?

Comment: The primary class is a text box with a popup controller. The hierarchy is popup controller -> navigation controller -> subclassed table view controller. The subclassed table view is just used for this single instance. Do you see a better way to structure this?

Comment: There is the option to extend the class with [Categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no inner or nested classes in Objective-C.  You need to make your helper a separate top-level class.

You can put the helper in its own `.h`/`.m` files, or, since only your primary class needs to see it, you can put it entirely in your primary class's `.m` file.  That is, you can do this:

```
// In Primary.m

#import "Primary.h"

@interface PrimaryHelper : UITableViewController
// PrimaryHelper interface declarations here
@end

@implementation PrimaryHelper
// PrimaryHelper implementation here
@end

@implementation Primary
// Primary implementation here
@end
```

However, if the helper class implementation is more than 30-40 lines, you will probably find it easier to manage if you just put it in its own files.

Comment: With this approach how would you declare properties/methods so that they are available to the primary class. Normally this is done in the .h file.

Comment: Everything that you would put in the helper's `.h` file and `.m` file, you just put in the primary's `.m` file.